# Octave: Need to reload programs after using xlsread

Tags: excel, octave

I'm running Octave 5.1.0.

After running the following code my editor window goes blank and I need to reload all programs. Octave itself is still running though, and data from the Excel file loads into memory.

```
clear;
pkg load 'io'
pkg load 'windows'
filename = 'DataFile.xlsx';
InData= xlsread (filename,'Sheet1');
```

I don't get any error messages.

It's a minor nuisance, but still a nuisance. Does anybody know how to address this?

Comment: I don't know the exact answer to your problem, and it would be useful to confirm there isn't a bug report on this, and add one if appropriate. Having said that, please read [this wiki entry](https://wiki.octave.org/IO_package). It likely covers the source of your problem. In particular, note the bit that talks about the use of the `windows` package only supporting a very specific interface, and only for pre-existing 32-bit excel installations. In any case, I would opt for another excel-reading interface, e.g. 'OCT', or failing that, the 'POI' one as per the code snipped mentioned there.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I tried `InData= xlsread (filename,'Sheet1',[],'OCT')`; but it  didn't make a difference. I'll continue by checking the bug reports and reading the wiki a bit more thoroughly.